# Disable the popup notification using Koltin on Android with NotificationListenerService

Tags: android, kotlin, notificationlistenerservice

I want to Disable the notifications similar to DND mode, but without using it, I am using NotificationListenerService and it works great the notification not show up in the notification list on my phone and also no sound using this code

```
override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        // Intercept the notification
        if (MainActivity.BLOCK_ALL) {
            val notification = sbn.notification

            // Cancel the notification visual display
            cancelNotification(sbn.key)

            // Check if the notification has sound
            if (notification.flags and Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT == Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT) {
                // If the notification has sound, mute it
                notification.sound = null
                notification.defaults = 0
                notification.flags = notification.flags and Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT.inv()

                // Re-notify the modified notification
                val notificationManager =
                    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
                val uniqueId = sbn.key.hashCode() // Convert the String key to an integer
                notificationManager.notify(uniqueId, notification)
            }
        }

    }
```

but i have and issue i don't want the notification popup for few seconds to also not show, so what i should edit in my code if something like this is possible to make it more clear here is a screenshot of what i want to block.

[image: popup notification]

so how can I block this so it did not popup like this and just make the mobile never show anything while my service is running?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

To disable popup notifications using Kotlin on Android with NotificationListenerService, you can follow these steps:

#1. Create a new class that extends NotificationListenerService.

```
class MyNotificationListener : NotificationListenerService() {
    // ...
}
```

#2. Override the onNotificationPosted method to intercept the notifications when they are posted.

```
override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification?) {
    // Check if the notification is a popup notification
    if (sbn?.notification?.priority ?: 0 >= NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH) {
        // Cancel the notification
        cancelNotification(sbn?.key)
    } else {
        // Pass the notification to the super class
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn)
    }
}
```

You check if the priority of the notification is higher than or equal to PRIORITY_HIGH, which is the priority level used by popup notifications. If it is, we cancel the notification using the cancelNotification method. If the priority level is lower than PRIORITY_HIGH, you pass the notification to the super class using super.onNotificationPosted.

#3. You need to declare the BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE permission, which is required to use NotificationListenerService. you also declare our MyNotificationListener service, and specify that it requires the BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE permission. You also add an intent-filter with the NotificationListenerService action.

#4. Start the MyNotificationListener service by calling startService from your app's main activity or another appropriate location.

```
startService(Intent(this, MyNotificationListener::class.java))
```

Please try these steps and let me know.
I think it will help you.
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, i have already the class, and i start the service correctly, but still the WhatsApp message show up at the top like in the screenshot.

Comment: Did you check the priority?

Comment: Yes i had checked, the issue not in checking priority because i canceled the notification anyway, i use the same function for all the notification for all apps, and still the notification popup.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow.  It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since most or all 6 of recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: The much higher answer rate and the verboseness suggest this has been generated by [ChatGPT_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned).